# Can I flatten an array without making a new list/array?

Tags: python, arrays, list, flatten

Let's say I have `arr = [[1], [0, 0], [2], [3], [0, 0], [4]]`

Could I flatten this into `[1, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4]` without having to use itertools, map/reduce, or a list comp? I am struggling to figure out a way to do this. Thanks.

This is what I have tried so far, it is a leetcode question: https://leetcode.com/problems/duplicate-zeros/

```py
class Solution:
    def duplicateZeros(self, arr: List[int]) -> None:
        """
        Do not return anything, modify arr in-place instead.
        
        """
        for ix in range(len(arr) - 2):
            if arr[ix] == 0:
                arr[ix] = [0, 0]
                del arr[-1]
            else:
                l = []
                l.append(arr[ix])
                arr[ix] = l

# Output when you return arr is [[1],[0, 0],[2],[3],[0, 0],[4]]
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use a list comprehension ? It seems to be the best solution to flatten a list.

Comment: "without having to use itertools, map/reduce, or a list comp" - that seems really arbitrary. Why rule out those tools? If you knew of something else that could flatten nested lists, would you have ruled that out too?

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Could you point out why you don't want to use list comprehensions, itertools, etc.? Comprehensions allow quite simple and Pythonic solutions: `[x for items in arr for x in items]`

Comment: Arbitrary ruling out things to use [check] - No code yet [check] - Homework?

Comment: One way can be: `list(list(zip(*arr))[0])` it's really bad answer ... someone can answer it well

Comment: It's a leetcode question. I've edited my my question to show what I've tried so far.

Comment: That leetcode problem has nothing to do with what you're asking for. Flattening nested lists isn't involved at all.

Comment: right, but that's the approach i took towards tackling the problem. Sure its messy but I am kinda disappointed with the reaction to my question. Dunno why it warrants these downvotes (my fault for not be specific enough pre-edit I guess)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- We can also use the [list copy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) (`[:]`) here, for solving the problem:

```
class Solution:
    def duplicateZeros(self, A):
        """
        Do not return anything, modify arr in-place instead.
        """
        A[:] = [x for num in A for x in ([num] if num else [0, 0])][:len(A)]
```

- Additionally, the optimal solution would be an order of N runtime with constant memory. That's already been addressed by LeetCode [here](https://leetcode.com/problems/duplicate-zeros/solution/):

```
class Solution:
    def duplicateZeros(self, arr: List[int]) -> None:
        """
        Do not return anything, modify arr in-place instead.
        """

        possible_dups = 0
        length_ = len(arr) - 1

        # Find the number of zeros to be duplicated
        for left in range(length_ + 1):

            # Stop when left points beyond the last element in the original list
            # which would be part of the modified list
            if left > length_ - possible_dups:
                break

            # Count the zeros
            if arr[left] == 0:
                # Edge case: This zero can't be duplicated. We have no more space,
                # as left is pointing to the last element which could be included  
                if left == length_ - possible_dups:
                    arr[length_] = 0 # For this zero we just copy it without duplication.
                    length_ -= 1
                    break
                possible_dups += 1

        # Start backwards from the last element which would be part of new list.
        last = length_ - possible_dups

        # Copy zero twice, and non zero once.
        for i in range(last, -1, -1):
            if arr[i] == 0:
                arr[i + possible_dups] = 0
                possible_dups -= 1
                arr[i + possible_dups] = 0
            else:
                arr[i + possible_dups] = arr[i]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply do:

```
arr = sum(arr, [])
```

What you are doing here is adding the iterable elements of arr taking an empty array `[]` as initial value.

Comment: This is extremely inefficient - it's quadratic time.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I agree, I do not argue about this. Mine is just another possible solution that when I posted was in accordance with the question requirements (do not use list comprehension, map, reduce, do not create a new list). As you can see the question requirements are quite restrictive, and I'm noticing that they are also changing, it has already been edited several times.
Maybe it is not the best solution, it is a possible solution. If there are better ones I will be happy to learn something too

Answer (score 1):

Try some recursion:

```
def flatten(lst):
    ans = []
    for el in lst:
        if type(el) == list:
             for e in flatten(el):
                 ans.append(e)
        else:
            ans.append(el)
    return ans
```

It will flatten any-dimensionanal lists.